# How can I center a multiple line text on an image in this case?

Tags: html, css

I have an image that takes up the whole screen. Now I want to have centered text over it. The method that I'm using works great for single line text but when I have two lines, it centers the longest line and aligns all other lines to the left of the longest one. How can I make all of them centered?

Here's the class that I'm using to center my text over the image:

```
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align:center;`

```
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align:center;
}
```

Updated demo at https://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/eeoKyo

Comment: Oh god... I just realized why it didn't work before. I tried doing `text-align:centered;` instead of `text-align:center;`. I feel really dumb now haha. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

and if the tests adding each line in a block of `<p>` would be easier for you and would allow you to center content without problem
for example

```css
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  
}
```

```html
<h1 class="centered">
    <p>lorem ipsun</p>
    <p>holamigo</p>
  </h1>
```